# Kusto table - How to recover soft-deleted data that is retained by the Recoverability = enabled set

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, retention, kusto-explorer

I have a Kusto database with the following retention policy:

```
{
  "SoftDeletePeriod": "30.00:00:00",
  "Recoverability": "Enabled"
}
```

Yesterday some data was removed from a table in the database since it was over 30 days old.

According to the [retention policy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy), if the Recoverability attribute is set, "`If set to Enabled, the data will be recoverable for 14 days after it's been soft-deleted.`"

My question is what is the query I execute to recover the soft-deleted data that has been lost?

I'm guessing it's something like:

`.<name-of-command> table <tableName>;`? Maybe there's an option somewhere to specify just how many days to recover? How do I recover soft-deleted data that is retained by the Recoverability=enabled set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a recovery currently requires opening a support ticket, via the Azure portal:

[image]

Comment: is still requires opening a support ticket via the Azure Portal or we can do that by Kusto directly?

Comment: Still requires a support ticket